# Read an excel file with Multi-Index and Single Index as columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I have the following dataframe in an excel File: the following code provides this dataframe:

```
    arrays = [['hello1','hello2','hello3], ['train', 'val']]
columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(arrays, names=('Statistic', 'database'))
            
            df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Bye1','Bye2'])
            df2.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([(c, '') for c in df2])
            df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns = columns)
            dfb = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
            dfb.to_excel('dfb.xlsx')
```

The excel dataframe does not have any rows. Now, when I want to get the dataframe from excel, I cannot get the exact MultiIndex: when I use the following code:

```
df = pd.readl_excel("dfb.xlsx", index_col = 0, header=[0,1], names = dfb.columns.names)
```

I have the following df index:

```
MultiIndex([(       'hello1',               'train'),
            (       'hello1',                 'val'),
            (       'hello2',               'train'),
            (       'hello2',                 'val'),
            (       'hello3',               'train'),
            (       'hello3',                 'val'),           
            (     'Bye1',               'train'),
            (     'Bye1',                 'val'),
            (     'Bye2',               'train'),
            (     'Bye2',                 'val'),
            (     'Bye1', 'Unnamed: 11_level_1'),
            (     'Bye2', 'Unnamed: 12_level_1')],
            names=['greetings', 'data'])
```

When, actually, what I want is:

```
MultiIndex([(       'hello1',               'train'),
            (       'hello1',                 'val'),
            (       'hello2',               'train'),
            (       'hello2',                 'val'),
            (       'hello3',               'train'),
            (       'hello3',                 'val'),           
            (       'Bye1',                      ''),
            (       'Bye2',                      '')],
            names=['greetings', 'data'])
```

Could someone help me?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly use `map()` method:

```
df.columns=df.columns.map('_'.join)
```

Now filter out columns:

```
df=df[df.columns[0:-2]]
```

Then use `filter()`,`isin()`,`tolist()` and `rename()` method:

```
df.columns=df.columns[~df.columns.isin(df.filter(like='Bye').columns)].tolist()+df.filter(like='Bye').rename(columns=lambda x:x.split('_')[0]+'_').columns.tolist()
```

Finally use `split()` method:

```
df=df.columns.str.split('_',expand=True)
```